# Elasticsearch : constant_score query vs bool.filter query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to achieve an exact match result using Elasticsearch (so I don't care about scoring here)

I see that there are 2 ways to do this :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "exact_match_field" : "hello world !"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "exact_match_field": "hello world !"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both work and gives me the result I want. Whats the difference between them ? Are there performance benefits of using one vs the other ?

(I am using Elasticsearch V 5.6)

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constant score query gives an equal score to any matching document irrespective of any scoring factors like `TF, IDF` etc. This can be used when you don't care whether how much a doc matched but just if a doc matched or not and give a score too, unlike filter.

A constant_score query takes a boost argument that is set as the score for every returned document when combined with other queries. By default boost is set to 1.

If you are interested below link will give you more insight

https://www.compose.com/articles/elasticsearch-query-time-strategies-and-techniques-for-relevance-part-ii/

Comment: Thank you ! Any idea of performance differences between them ?

Comment: Also, how is bool.filter different ? Is it just the boost param ?

Comment: constant_score will be more performant as it doesn't have to score each document based on there TF and IDF factors unlike in bool.filter it has to score each document

Comment: hmm, please let me know if I am wrong here, but bool.filter, from here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html , says that it does not score docs. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, you are right my bad, To sum up: Use filter for filter and constant_score when you need the score.