# Is there performance difference between constant_score and bool query using filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, booleanquery

When it comes to the "performance difference", I read nothing reliable till now.

Based on its official docs, as to filter used in the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must **the score of the query will be ignored**. Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for **caching**.

As for [constant score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)

> Filter queries **do not calculate** relevance scores. To speed up performance, Elasticsearch automatically **caches** frequently used filter queries.

---

#### Just a guess

Constant query will not calculate (TF-IDF or more advanced algs), while the bool query will do the calculation but return 0 (ignoring it); so the constant query is more performant.

Besides when it comes to a specified score, you have to use constant score query instead of bool query which only will return 0.

QAs I just read: [Elasticsearch : constant_score query vs bool.filter query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142871/elasticsearch-constant-score-query-vs-bool-filter-query)

Answer (score 0):

NO, there is no performance difference since they are the same.

Based on again its offical doc discussing about [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-filter-context.html#filter-context):

> In a filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or No — **no scores are calculated.**

And

> Filter context is in effect whenever a query clause is passed to a filter parameter, such as the filter or must_not parameters in the bool query, the filter parameter in the constant_score query, or the filter aggregation.