# Ignore term frequency but use positions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a text field and i want to ignore term frequencies in scoring but keep positions to have match phrase search ability.

and my index define like this:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/my-index-001' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "mappings": {
        "autocomplete": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "row_autocomplete"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "row_autocomplete"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "row_autocomplete": {
                    "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["icu_folding", "autocomplete_filter", "lowercase"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**index data**:

```
[
    {
        "title": "university",
        "name": "london and EC london English"
    },
    {
        "title": "city",
        "name": "london"
    }
]
```

I want city get high score when I execute match query like this:

```
POST _search

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "london"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "london",
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and they got different score(university is greater than city actually) because of term frequency, What I want is only count term frequency one time, and according to `fieldLength`, city's `fieldLength` is less than university's `fieldLength`, so if I can ignore repeat `termFreq`, the score of city will greater than university refer to elasticsearch's rule:

```
GET _explain

# city's _explain
{
    "value": 2.0785222,
    "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
    "details": [
        {
            "value": 6.0,
            "description": "termFreq=6.0",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 2.0,
            "description": "fieldLength",
            "details": []
        },
        ...
    ]
}

# university's explain
{
    "value": 2.1087635,
    "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
    "details": [
        {
            "value": 24.0,
            "description": "termFreq=24.0",
            "details": []
        },
        {
            "value": 29.0,
            "description": "fieldLength",
            "details": []
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

There are something I tried, for example In index mapping i can set index_options=docs to ignore term frequencies but this disables term positions and i cant use match phrase query anymore.

Does anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [constant score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) that wraps a filter query and returns every matching document with a relevance score equal to the boost parameter value.

**If you use a `constant score query`, then your match query will give no score apart from just 0 or 1. This is because it will just act like a filter that will just if the query matches or not. `match` query will not act like a matching based on full-text search.**

> A constant_score query takes a boost argument that is set as the score
> for every returned document when combined with other queries. By
> default boost is set to 1.

Refer this to get detailed explaination on [bool filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#score-bool-filter) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143164/10348758) to understand difference between constant score query and bool filter.

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result.

**Index data**

```
{ "name": "london only" }
{ "name": "london and London" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": "london"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "london and london"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "london only"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: thanks, @Bhavya, Maybe I didn't report my question clearly, I've tried constant_score query, and that's not what I want, I will edit my question again to make it accurate, anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I indexed both the sample documents what you provided using default index mapping, so both `title` and `name` fields are text fields. and used same your query and it returns me the high score for just doc which contains just `london` as shown below:

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "matchrel",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.51518387,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "city",
                    "name": "london"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "matchrel",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.41750965,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "university",
                    "name": "london university and EC London English"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Also, As you have not explained your use case in details, and with limited info, It seems it can be easily achieved with below query with also returns more score for `london` doc:

{
"query": {
"match_phrase": {
"name": "london"
}
}
}

**And its search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "matchrel",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.25759193, // note score
                "_source": {
                    "title": "city",
                    "name": "london"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "matchrel",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.20875482,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "university",
                    "name": "london university and EC London English"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I did forgot to mention my analyzer, I've edit my question again, thanks for your help.